# Can't access one model's instance variables from another model) (self.ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have two models, Draft and Pick.  Draft creates an array of available Players in an instance variable named 'available_players'.  This is done using the 'before_save' callback.  The callback runs the instance method 'start' which in turn runs 'set_active_players'.  I've tested all of this in my Draft_spec and I have no problems loading players and having them returned in the available_players array.  All my draft specs pass.

The problem is that when I try to access the 'available_players' instance variable from Pick.rb, it returns nil.  If I call 'draft.start' (the instance method that should run before Draft.rb saves), I can suddenly access the 'available_players' array... it's like the Draft object is not creating the available_players array even though I have the before_save method in place.

Here is the code that fails inside of Pick.rb:

```
def available_players_returns_nil
    @draft_object.available_players
end
```

Here is the code that works inside of Pick.rb:

```
def available_players_working
    @draft_object.start
    @draft_object.available_players
end
```

I don't want to have to call start every time I call the method because available_players should not need to reload ALL Players.  Please help me access available_players!

Links: [failing Pick specs](https://github.com/Cheex11/drafter/blob/master/spec/models/pick_spec.rb), [Pick.rb](https://github.com/Cheex11/drafter/blob/master/app/models/pick.rb)

EDIT:
I should add that @draft_object is found using

```
@draft_object = Draft.find(self.draft_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, this is wrong:

```
@draft_object = Draft.find(self.draft_id)
```

You have an association set up, so use it. You can simply use `draft` within your `Pick` object to access the `Draft` it belongs to. No need to assign it to an instance variable called `@draft_object`.

Same story with `player`.

Incidentally, your `set_available_players` method in `Draft` is just looping through all of the players and adding them to an instance variable. Why are you doing this? Why don't you simply grab the players directly if you need them in `Pick`? Like this:

```
@players = Player.all
```

Also ... I'm somewhat concerned that pretty much all of your tests are commented out. I hope that's not by design?

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much for the trick with associations.  I had no idea I could simply call draft within the Pick object.  As for Player.all, I am trying to set an array of Player objects so that every draft can have a set of Players.  The thought here is that as a player is drafted, the player will be moved from available_players to drafted_players (which has not been added yet).  And for the tests, I quickly commented all tests out before committing to try and simplify the question before asking you guys.

Comment: You should use `Player.all` directly, until you've written your `drafted_players` method. Then you can write `available_players` as `Player.all - drafted_players`